# Android Studio? How long a key is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was trying to develop a basic application, I wanted to add feature of *how long a key is pressed.*

Basically I am trying to make a small game.

I just want to know that how can I detect in application that how long the key is been pressed. However the key must not be pressed multiple times the input must not be given.

The key pressed once, the application should start calculating time from the beginning when the key got pressed to the point when it got released.

Any idea related to this and if code can be given it would be helpful.
Thank you:)

Comment: u mean your app should calculate all this not android studio!!!

Comment: What do you mean by key? Key on keyboard or button?

Comment: yes, app must calculate..

Comment: key on keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a key event listener for when the button is pressed and released, and for both use the System.currentTimeMillis() method. Subtract the first "time" with the later one, and you have how long the button has been pressed

Comment: If I do that, the key is pressed consecutively, Assume, I want input D for 5 seconds but the input comes as DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD when pressed for long time. How Do I avoid that?